# Fast MP4 thumbnails

Tags: windows, video, command-line, mp4

I [have worked with](https://superuser.com/q/597945) FFmpeg, AtomicParsley and
Mp4Box in the past to set MP4 thumbnails. However today I realized that
[MediaMonkey](http://mediamonkey.com) can also set them, and fast.

The previous three programs listed all had to rewrite the entire file to do
this, while I have found that MediaMonkey can set the thumbnail without a full
rewrite. This takes the processing time per file from about 1 minute to about 1
second.

I would prefer a command line program that can do what MediaMonkey is doing. Can
any of the ones I have listed be made to do this, or is another command line
program available that can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg has an [open issue](//trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2798) on this functionality. In the meantime, covers
can be added with the [TagEditor project](//github.com/Martchus/tageditor). To add:

```
tageditor -s cover=ju.jpg --max-padding 100000 -f ki.m4a
```

To remove:

```
tageditor -s cover= --max-padding 100000 -f ki.m4a
```